# How to change var out of function in js

Tags: angularjs, global-variables

I want to change var in js according to below Code:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">

        var dataRes;
        ersalvetabeApi()

        function ersalvetabeApi() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Api/Test',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    //  dataRes=data[0]
                    dataRes = data;
                    console.log(data[0]);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Error in Operation');
                }
            });
        }

        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
        myApp.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
         //this.array = $window.dataRes;
            this.array = $window.dataRes;

        }]);
    </script>
```

When I use this code, this code not work. But when I used `alert(datares)` under `ersalvetabeApi()` this work. I don't want to use alert.

Please help to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i can resolve it. may be need for everybody.
my Code:

```js
   var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
            myApp.factory('valueService', function ($interval) {
                var service = {
                   ue: "hjk",
                };

                return service;
            });



            myApp.controller('SomeController', function ($scope, $interval, valueService) {
               

               // start();      // this line will execute when constructor initiates, starting the whole thing.
                // valueService.value = "45356";
                start();

                function start() {
                        $interval(function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/Api/Test',
                                type: 'GET',
                                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                                    //  dataRes=data[0]
                                    dataRes = data;
                                    valueService.ue = data;
                                    console.log(valueService.ue[0].id);
                                },
                                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    console.log('Error in Operation');
                                }
                            });
                        }, 1000,2);
                }
            });


            myApp.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, valueService) {
                $scope.message = 'Another Controller';
                $scope.valueService = valueService;
               // this.array = valueService;
            });
```

```html
 <div ng-controller="SomeController">
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div ng-controller="TestCtrl as ctrl">
            <span ng-repeat="entry in valueService.ue track by $index">
                {{ entry.name }}+"/"
            </span>
            {{message}}
        </div
```

GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an async call to the server, but running angular application synchronically, so when you reach angular code, value not assigned to window variable yet.

```
var dataRes;
ersalvetabeApi().then(function () {
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
    //this.array = $window.dataRes;
    this.array = $window.dataRes;
    }]);
});

function ersalvetabeApi() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: '/Api/Test',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        //  dataRes=data[0]
        dataRes = data;
        console.log(data[0]);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Error in Operation');
    }
  });
}
```

Try to wrap your code which should be called after data returned from ajax call. Now it will run asynchronously.

Comment: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined , this error is accure

Comment: tnx for answering Mikki :) but not work to me! give me same error : 
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: Could you create plunker, and I will resolve it for you!

Comment: i d'ont no what is this ,but i'm very tnx for answering